# Email functionality not working. Gives http 500 error page when moved to 64-bit server

Tags: email, asp-classic, smtp

I have a classic ASP application which is functioning properly in a 32-bit server. I want to move it to a 64 bit server but one issue that I'm facing is that my email functionality doesn't seem to work. 
What I'm using is a third party mail client called 'ASPQ'.
I cannot share the work due to security reasons.

But the basic structure looks like:

`

```
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("aspqclientname") 
   objMail.RemoteHost = "host.name"
   objMail.TimeOut = 600
   objMail.QMessage = True
   objMail.From = strMailSender
   objMail.Subject = "Mailing: OnBoarding Survey"
   objMail.To = "sample.mail@mail.com"  
   objMail.ContentType = "text/html"
   objMail.TextBody = "body"
   If Not 
   objMail.Send 
   Then
      If objMail.Response <> "" Then
         strError = objMail.Response
      Else
        strError = "Unknown"
      End If
      Response.Write "Mail failure occured. Reason: " & strError
      Response.End
   End If
   Set objMail = Nothing
```

`

Comment: Enabling 32 bit applications could indeed solve the problem.  As it's a third party component another possible problem is that your website's IUSR account doesn't have read/execute permissions on the component's dll.  If you have no luck getting ASPQ to work, there's always CDOSYS, which ships with Windows Server. http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Comment: Also, I frequently recommend this page to anyone developing in Classic ASP.  it tells you how to get detailed error messages rather than just a 500 internal server error page. http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: @John Yeah do have a classic CDO back up for this which is working fine. Just want to give a final try so as not to change or tweak the code. Thanks for the above link BTW. :)

Comment: @John One doubt though, will using CDO require any purchase or registration with Microsoft?

Comment: It requires no registration.  Assuming of course that your Windows Server itself is legitimate  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that the ASPQ mail component is built as a 32 bit only application. You can try and see if they have a 64 bit version which you can install/register on your 64 bit server.

Alternatively you can try running the application on your 64 bit server in an app pool with 32 bit "compatibility mode" enabled. Open up IIS manager find the appropriate app pool for your site, right click and open the Advanced Settings option. You should see an option to "Enable 32-Bit Applications" which needs to be set to **True**.

[image]

nb: I'd recommend running the site in it's own application pool if not already doing so.

Comment: Hmm, This escaped me. I mean the IIS setting thing.Will try and let you know.

Comment: @Abhid might depend on what version of IIS you are running. I presumed it was IIS7 or IIS8.

Comment: I tried the Enable 32 bit option, but with no success. :(  Looks like I need to find the 64-bit dll...